# Wordpress contact form 7 to show the form dropdown menus as like

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I am using [contact-form-7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for one of my form in the site. In that I have some dropdown options. The option are mainly consists of some come courses with their names. Like `course 1, course 2, course 3, course 4....so on`. But I want that my course field should be seen like this

**Course A:**

```
  course 1
  course 2
  course 3
  course 4
```

**Course B:**

```
  course 1
  course 2
  course 3
```

**Course C:**

```
  course 1
  course 2
```

**Course D:**

```
  course 1
  course 2
  course 3
```

Currently I have done this type of fields in my contact-form-7 plugin
 Course applied for`[select courser-applied class:course-applied "Course A" "course 1" "course 2" "course 3" "course 4" "Course B:" "course 1" "course 2" "course 3" "Course C:" "course 1" "course 2" "Course D:" "course 1" "course 2" "course3"]`
 But this one is not working as I want that course A,course B, course C, course D should come in strong character in dropdowns . So can someone kindly tell me how to do this?
Here how I want my form dropdown should look like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

-- Append parent_ to all your top level options' values like: parent_Course A, parent_Course B
-- Also add extra options with the value as "endparent" something like below structure

```
parent_Course A:
  course 1
  course 2
  course 3
  course 4
endparent
parent_Course B:
  course 1
  course 2
  course 3
endparent
```

**Code:**

```
// contact us form - change out optgroup labels
$(function() {
    // search for parent_ items
    var foundin = $('option:contains("parent_")');
    $.each(foundin, function(value) {
         var updated = $(this).val().replace("parent_","");
        // find all following elements until endparent
        $(this).nextUntil('option:contains("endparent")')
        .wrapAll('<optgroup label="'+ updated +'"></optgroup');
    });
    // remove placeholder options
    $('option:contains("parent_")').remove();
    $('option:contains("endparent")').remove();
});
```